# Java "get resource files" brings null after maven build

Tags: java, maven, build, resources

I have an application loading some resources logs, properties etc...

`URL pathUrl = this.getClass().getResource("../logs/logfile.log");`

or

`ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
 URL pathUrl = classLoader.getResource("../logs/logfile.log");`

or

`URL pathUrl = myClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("../logs/logfile.log");`

When I build it with maven into a jar application it brings null while it works fine before the build.

mvn pom.xml:

```
 <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
       </resource>
  </resources>
```

Any idea on how to get it working after the build?
Thank you!

Comment: When your class is loaded on the bootclasspath loader (which is null) ,you will get null.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your resource is not inside the ***src/main/resources*** directory since you are accessing the parent directory

> ../logs/logfile.log

When you say it works fine before the build I assume you run it with an IDE which will probably try to access the resource from the file system, so it can access ***src/main/resources***'s parent directory where it might find *logs/logfile.log*.

However you do not include the parent directory in the build process so there is no such resource file in the resulting jar.

Note that there is a difference between

```
this.getClass().getResource("../logs/logfile.log");
```

And

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../logs/logfile.log");
```

so that it is unlikely that both of them succeed even before the build. (unless you have created multiple logs/logfile.log files while testing)

Answer (score 0):

Try

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logs/logfile.log)